# I've always had a feeling that there is more to life and death. Is this normal?

Tags: mindfulness

Good morning,  to everyone,  I'm new to this site and only recently been very interested in Buddhism,  mainly because I have always believed in reincarnation,  but to be honest I didn't know other people had the same views.
So deep inside I have had this feeling but could not express how I feel to anyone as most people think I'm crazy.

But I am very interested in the life of how Buddhist lives and want to learn as much as I can regarding this religion. 
Any help would be very much appreciated.  Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not strange to have such feelings. Even from a logical standpoint, thinking that experiencing does not end at death is the right thing to believe.

Here are some related videos:

- [Reincarnation and Nibbana](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jxCEi4cQBA0)
- [Karma and Reincarnation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3kYQPou4p0)

But make sure you do not fall into the extreme of eternalism - believing that a person goes from life to live or taking the mental stream of thoughts as a soul.

Answer (score 1):

first of all let me congratulate you for having this feeling bcs many are in the drunken state of life issues. the very existing you now is the greatest proof that you existed previously and have gathered causes to enable you in rebirth. learning truth of rebirth is rejoicing bcs we aasure ourselves that i am going to be there in next birth after i will be dead in this birth. The deathfear is slightly smoothened . But according to buddha ,  there is rebirth or it is not there also. whole thing depend on you. if you are content in this life and also hope the same shall be in next life also then go on happily. But a little fraction of the futility of life comes to know you though temporarily through any means for e.g love break,cheating partner,loss in career ,deceived by friend or may be due to unknown reasons then the search begins to get rid of causes causing this. then the knowledge begins , what are the causes for getting this life . when learnt ,one strives to avoid them to avoid next birth. buddha's teachings are for this only. i suggest to read "art of living by william harts ,a very convincing analysis of buddha's teachings as taught by goenka guruji who is in lineage of lady sayadaw,sayagyi u ba khin . as per my personal experience i immediately grasped the analysis and feel blessed for  developing faith in the teachings of buddha. hoping and heartily wishing to develop the same in you also.bcs we are all diseased and once the diagnosis is done treatment can be done by a neighbourhood chemist also.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't more to life and death.  Buddhism, at its heart, is living and dying wholeheartedly.  Nothing more.

Answer (score -3):

A quest for a spiritual side to life is normal for human beings, as contrary to animals we have not only a body but also a soul. So, if as you are saying you always have had a feeling that there is more to life and death - this is normal.

Comment: Strangely, this is a non-buddhist view!  Buddhism, via anatta, repudiates the soul, and moreover acknowledges the rebirth of animals. We have all been born as animals many times.